# Add link to image

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I need to add a hyperlink to an image. Here is my code. how do I add link to the image?

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  $.each( data, function( idx, obj ) {
  //   $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", '/images/' + obj.Icon ).attr("title", obj.DisplayName).appendTo( "#images" );
});
```

Comment: This greatly depends on what the actual value of `data` is.. Can you post a snippet of the data output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `obj` also contains the link address, and pretending that `obj.Href` is where it lives:

```
$.each( data, function( idx, obj ) {
  var i = $( "<img>" ).
    attr( "src", '/images/' + obj.Icon );

  $('a').
    attr('href', obj.Href).
    attr("title", obj.DisplayName).
    append(i).
    appendTo( "#images" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
    $("<img>").attr({
        src: '/images/' + obj.Icon,
        title: obj.DisplayName,
    }).appendTo("#images").wrap('<a href="url">');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/py25pL3c/